# While writing in Greek, I need to keep citations and bibliography in English

Tags: bibliographies, greek

i have just been introduced to LaTeX as a means to write my dissertation. I am faced with the problem of writing my document in Greek while keeping all bibliographic entries and citations in English. This is a minimal working example with the exact set of packages I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{graphicx}
\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300

\begin{document}

Το φύλο αυτό των φυκών, αποτελεί επικράτεια των Βακτηρίων\citep{GarciaPichel2009107}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}

%this is the entry in the bib.bib file
@incollection\{GarciaPichel2009107,
title = "Cyanobacteria ",
editor = "Schaechter, Moselio ",
booktitle = "Encyclopedia of Microbiology (Third Edition) ",
publisher = "Academic Press",
edition = "Third Edition",
address = "Oxford",
year = "2009",
pages = "107 - 124",
isbn = "978-0-12-373944-5",
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-012373944-5.00250-9",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780123739445002509",
author = "F. Garcia-Pichel",
keywords = "benthos",
keywords = "blue-green algae",
keywords = "cell differentiation",
keywords = "chlorophyll",
keywords = "extreme environments",
keywords = "nitrogen fixation",
keywords = "photoautotrophy",
keywords = "photosynthesis",
keywords = "phycobiliproteins",
keywords = "plankton",
keywords = "primary production",
keywords = "symbiosis",
language = "English",
keywords = "toxins "
\}
```

This is the output i get, when i wish it to be in English (instead, all characters are "translated" to their Greek variants):
[image]

Comment: Just put `\selectlanguage{english}` right before `\bibliography{bib}`.

Comment: That fixes one problem. The bibliogrphic entries are now in english. But, the citations in the text are still in greek.
-->ok i have used \selectlanguage{english}\citep{...}\selectlanguage{greek}. This is kind of a bore but it works :) thnx for the quick reply!

Answer (score 5):

You should use `biblatex`: it has a natbib emulation, knows about your main language, whether you use babel or polyglossia (with xelatex), and it defines a `langid field` for each entry in your database. So the entry will be printed in its own language with its own hyphenation rules. If you use polyglossia, you also have a `langidopts` field that manages dialects of a language (e.g. Ποντιακά or american english).

See §2.2.3, pp.23-24 of the documentation. See also § 3.1.2.1, pp. 46-47,*General preamble options*, about `language=autobib, autocite, auto`.

Comment: I tried using biblatex but i got the error that it wasnt compatible with utf8x.

Comment: @Panas You could try `utf8` instead (I'm not sure whether that's enough for Greek support) or use a properly UTF-8 enabled engine such as XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and fontspec, there's no problem. @¨Panas: With PDFLaTeX, if problems happen only on loading biblatex, maybe the reason is that your .bib file is not utf8 encoded. Try to encode it in utf8 (JabRef can do that) and run biber.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different command for Latin alphabet citation, I propose `\lcitep`; next, add some code to the internal command `\bibsection` in order to tell TeX to use the Latin alphabet in the bibliography.

I used `article` just to get a single page, use `report` for your document without any other change. You might add also other commands such as `\lcitet` and so on, depending on which ones you use.

The `filecontents*` environment is just for convenience in the example. Use your `.bib` file as the argument to `\bibliography`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{GarciaPichel2009107,
  title = "Cyanobacteria ",
  editor = "Schaechter, Moselio ",
  booktitle = "Encyclopedia of Microbiology (Third Edition) ",
  publisher = "Academic Press",
  edition = "Third Edition",
  address = "Oxford",
  year = "2009",
  pages = "107 - 124",
  isbn = "978-0-12-373944-5",
  doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-012373944-5.00250-9",
  url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780123739445002509",
  author = "F. Garcia-Pichel",
  keywords = "benthos",
  keywords = "blue-green algae",
  keywords = "cell differentiation",
  keywords = "chlorophyll",
  keywords = "extreme environments",
  keywords = "nitrogen fixation",
  keywords = "photoautotrophy",
  keywords = "photosynthesis",
  keywords = "phycobiliproteins",
  keywords = "plankton",
  keywords = "primary production",
  keywords = "symbiosis",
  language = "English",
  keywords = "toxins "
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{graphicx}
\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300

\DeclareRobustCommand{\lcitep}[1]{%
  \textlatin{\citep{#1}}%
}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\bibsection}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Το φύλο αυτό των φυκών, αποτελεί επικράτεια των Βακτηρίων \lcitep{GarciaPichel2009107}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: @egreg if you have both greek and english bibliography what's the solution? we use for english \lcitep but for a greek resource?

Comment: @giannis The only sensible choice is going `biblatex` and XeLaTeX.

Comment: @giannis You shouldn't downvote a post just because it answers a different problem than yours.

Answer (score 1):

Greek text
english and greek bibliography

I managed to do it with these settings

(pdflatex + biber)

```
....

\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=ynt,babel=other,bibencoding=auto, language=autobib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample2.bib} %file of biblatex

....
```

This after all use packages

```
\newcommand{\sw}{\selectlanguage{english}}
```

and in the bibliography section

```
\section{Αναφορές - Βιβλιογραφία}
\selectlanguage{english}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={\textgreek{Αναφορές}}]
```

Hope this helps.
After one and a half year full of LaTeX I managed to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
```

and in the bibliography section use

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \nocite{*} 
    \bibliography{References}
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Now the bibliography is in englih, but the text in the document too. But it should be in greek ...

Comment: Tell me if it works now. CEID everywhere